# How do I open a shapefile in QGIS for upload to Garmin GPSmap 62?

Tags: qgis, gps

I now have a polygon and have successfully raised 25 random sample points and saved as a shapefile. I have checked that GPS utility and the shapefile are set at EPSG:27700 BNG but when I try and open the sample points shapefile in GPS utility it says cannot open shapefile.

Can anybody help and is there an easy solution?

Answer (score 1):

If all else fails, export the point layer as GPX and upload that directly to your GPS device.

Comment: Thank you. I am learning Quantum and GPS utility. Is there a simple way to do what you say, as I have tried but can't find a way to do that please?

Comment: In the main menu: Layer -> Save As -> GPX. You should also change the CRS dropdown to Selected and then use WGS 84 (lat/lon), which is the usual way they are stored in. I wouldn't count on the device to know how to transform the coordinates, so it is more a file format standard flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

If you get weird behaviour trying to open a projected file, go back to lat/lon WGS84 and try that out.

1. Save your shapefile in WGS84 (EPSG 4326): right click and 'Save As' then set CRS to 4326 before saving.
2. Open in GPSUtility after changing to latlon/wgs84 in the main dialog.

Saving as a GPX for direct upload to your GPSMap62 is also a good option - but make sure you save as a GPX using EPSG:4326 because QGIS does NOT automatically change it on saving! The GPX format is **only** in lat/lon, WGS84, but QGIS will save the coordinates and datum of whatever the layer is unless you explicitly change it.